# Iceland Tax Free Refund

Tags: iceland, tax-refunds

I recently submitted a few tax free refunds in Keflavik airport with my debit card details handwritten on the receipt along with my name and address.

Unfamiliar with the process I did not get any form of receipt back from the clerk, just a thank you and a next customer please. In fact the clerk took the full receipt and didn't even give me my portion of the receipt back as proof of purchase.

Since I have returned home the debit card I asked for the refunds to be applied to has expired and I have a new card with a new long number across the middle.

Now the originally card has expired am I to expect the refund would not be able to be credited to my account as that card is no longer valid? Or is there a process in place by card companies to recognise this and still apply the credit?

Comment: In my case, their refund was quick (< 1 week), but was on xmas holidays so less people. I had a similar issue in past, I called the bank, they found the refund in their system and credited it on my new card, but every bank has a different way I reckon.

Comment: Usually refunds to expired cards will be processed as this is a relatively common situation with no risk involved for the cardholder, but things may vary from one card issuer to the next. You may want to call them to check.